# What is the least horrible way to center an element with CSS?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have html that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head> 

<body>

<header>
  <h1>Some title thing, who knows</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="one/">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="two/">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="three/">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

</body>
</html>
```

If I give `header` an auto margin and a width, it's horizontally centered. What's the least horrible way to ensure that it's vertically centered, as well?

I am aware of the following articles which provide some discussion of the topic:

- http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/
- http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/
- http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html
- http://www.brunildo.org/test/vertmiddle.html

Comment: Is it opposites day or something? Why not just say 'best'?

Comment: No, it's not opposites day. I mean it as a sort of [litotious](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes) statement to express my frustration with in working with CSS. In particular, a question that has launched a thousand blog posts over a decade should well have a _simple_ answer by the CSS3 spec, at least. I will be pleasantly surprised if I receive an answer to this question which is simple and does not require markup pollution. Thus, I look to the 'least horrible' answer.

Comment: I often wonder at the complete lack of support for elegant vertical alignment in CSS. It's incredible how such an important thing could've been left out by the standards committee.

Comment: Keep in mind that, in some cases, vertical centering doesn't actually matter, and a sufficiently large top margin will be just fine. Don't beat yourself up over this too much until confirming that it is, in fact, vital.

Comment: @Matchu Of course; I think I would go so far as to assert that just fudging vertical centering with a big-ish margin is one of the 'horrible' solutions to the problem as posed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since this question was tagged `CSS3`, here's a "least horrible" solution using CSS3's "flexbox". Unfortunately only recent versions of Safari, Chrome and Firefox support it.

```
html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
  background:#eee;
}
header {
  width:30em;
  background:#fff;
}
body {  
  display:box;
  box-pack:center;
  box-align:center;
  box-orient:horizontal;
}
```

A more complete demo [can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/8BZTs/).

Answer (score 4):

If you do NOT know the height of the `header` the only way I often use, requires extra html if done properly, tough you could do without.

You make the header `vertical-align: middle` by making it a `table-cell`

```
html{
    height: 100%;
}      
body {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
header {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

note that I set 100% height on the html node, which really isnt proper css as far as I know, it should be on the body and header should be in a encapsulating div wich has `display: table` http://jsfiddle.net/bgYPR/2/

Comment: There are no other styles present than that which you see in the html.

Comment: @troutwine: There must be at least a width defined otherwise `margin:0 auto` wouldn't have any discernible effect.

Comment: There's a width defined, sure, in my CSS and I mention that. But what I'm trying to _prompt_ is for you to share a little code. For the purposes of this question, there's just the html code. Now, what is the least awful way of getting that `header` smack in the middle of the page?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there's *still* nothing elegant for vertical alignment, only hacks.

Comment: Well, what's the least horrible hack for the HTML you see above?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a best way, but there are a number of different ways (depending on your situation), and many are thoroughly discussed [in this article](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/).

Comment: Used that article last time I had the problem. It seems to cover all the possible ways of doing it.

Comment: There are so many blog posts with 'solutions' contingent on context that you could choke on 'em. Yeah, that guy's method 3 looks nice but it takes _4_ steps to complete and a floater div. I haven't got a floater, just a header. There's also [this](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/) and any number of other posts you can find through googling "vertical center css". There _should_ be something authoritative. If we have to get together and wring our hands over context the tool is _broken_.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when I need vertical centering I use a pair of inline-block elements.  You have one element that is the full height of the container, and a second element that is only the height of the content to be centered.  Both are `display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle`.

I like to use b tags for this, because they have no semantic significance and are tiny:

```
<style>
    .mycontainer {text-align:center;}
    b.vcenter {display:inline-block;height:100%;width:1px;vertical-align:middle;}
    b.vcenter+b {display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;}
</style>

<div class="mycontainer">
    <b class="vcenter"></b><b>This is my centered content<br>It makes me happy!</b>
</div>
```

Mind you, this specific code example wont work in IE7 because of the lack of inline-block and sibling selectors (+), but the same technique can be done using more complex code that IE7 will handle.

Comment: Thank you. Would you be so kind as to target your answer to the HTML presented--editing it as required--and also be kind enough to include  IE7 functionality?

Comment: I didn't understand what exactly you were trying to center.  The entire header tag?  Is the header going to be the only thing in the document?  The IE7 code requires knowing the exact dimensions of the content, as the width and height of the content block must be defined.

Comment: Furthermore, IE7 doesn't support the header tag natively without adding a shim and default css, which you don't show.

Comment: Yes, for this post the header is the sole content of the page. Also, a fine point about this shiv: I've gone ahead and edited the top-post to include html5 shiv.

Answer (score 0):

I would generally not verticially center, but specify a small top margin like 20px. We don't always know enough about the end user's equipment to make an assumption about what is convenient or usable for the platform they are viewing the site on.

Comment: The OP is asking about **vertically** centering... so why are you talking about horizontal centering, 20 pixel margins and not knowing about the user's equipment?  Makes no sense really, since "centering" something is usually a _dynamic_ solution which is totally independent of any particular screen size. (that's the point) ... It compensates automatically.

Comment: Basically the explosion in mobile devices/browsers/internet tvs/widescreen ratios makes it very hard to know what (even well established) hack techniques will produce odd results in the wild. I fixed a site recently which was using the technique suggested by benjamin earlier but showing very odd results in different mobile browsers. It may be that a V center works very nicely in terms of design and usability on a desktop or mobile but turns out to be bad usability on a mobile touch platform.

Comment: Sparky, tired. Vertically was a typo. It makes complete sense when you think about the variety of equipment being used to view websites.

Comment: Mobile browsing is very popular.  It's so popular that the mobile browsers are becoming much more like desktop browsers... while, yet not so popular that most average website owners even need to worry about it.  If the mobile platform is mission-critical to your business model, then create an app for it.

Comment: Depends on your experience I guess, I work at a digital agency and see problems with 'hacks for look' like this on a fairly weekly basis. Website owners should VERY much worry about it because they will be living with their current choices for quite a long time. Also the issue I was highlighting was not just about code but also about usability. What looks great and works conveniently on traditional displays may not be so successful on others.

Comment: It's all besides the point really... IMHO, it's not a well constructed answer to the original question.  Actually, it's not an answer at all... he's not asking "whether or not" he should do it, but **how**.

Comment: IMHO if you should use a coding technique should be a very strong consideration - approach is a very important part of any technical job.

Comment: Yours is not an answer to the only question posed by the OP, _"What's the least horrible way to ensure that it's vertically centered as well?"_.  End of discussion.

Comment: @toomanyairmiles I appreciate your concern about usability, but this problem example is boiled down entirely to eschew such secondary concerns: it is only a problem of plopping an element into the center of a page without consideration of _how usable_ this will be on various devices. Might be that it's peachy, might not be or it might be that in the actual problem which spawned this one I'm _only_ targeting desktops. It's irrelevant to the question posed, but I do thank you for your time.

Comment: @troutwine No worries, I appreciate it was only tangentially related to the question but I thought it was worth raising the point.